# Meanings of MDX query icons in SQL Server IDE

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I've opened an MDX query in our IDE (SQL Server) and want to match the icons of the cube entities to the names I'm reading about.

- The small cube with the three axes must be an icon for a Dimension?
- What is the rectangle of 6 small blue squares?
- What is the small triangle of 6 small blue squares?

[image]

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the edit - do you ever use MDX? (it's hard for me to grasp after sql for 5hrs/day for past 5yrs!)

Comment: No, MDX is a big mystery to me :-)

Comment: @marc_s [apologies but couldn't help myself; just upped your last comment]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Cube with 3 axis represents `Dimension`.
2. Rectangle with 6 small cubes represents `Attribute Hierarchy` which is nothing but an hierarchy which is composed of a `Single Attribute`
3. The 3rd one represents `User Hierarchy` which is composed of more than one `attribute`

Comment: +1 thanks praveen: In MSDN they use the term `User-Defined Hierarchy` I assume this is the same as `User Hierarchy`? (I'm currently working through Art Tennick's book PRACTICAL MDX QUERIES)